# What is SpringBoot @SqsListener equivalent in quarkus if it is available and if not how to built the one?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs, quarkus, sqslistener

I searched in Quarkus documentation and the internet and documentation show how to receive messages from SQS using get call, but I want to receive the message a way springboot works with @sqsListener i.e. as soon as the message is sent to Sqs it will be polled, I am searching for its equivalent in quarkus. If there is any possibility for this please let me know, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-amazon-services